# How do I "uniquely" repeat a function n times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, raphael, repeat

so I have some code that draws a path and a circle. the circle is animated across the path every single time the function is initiated. I simply want to create 10 paths, each with their own circle that animates across each path. When I simply execute the function 10 times, the paths are generated fine, however the circle all animate along the same, single path. what am I doing wrong here? Is the best method here to create a for(i=0) loop?

You can view my code on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VEdwG/4/), or take a look at it here:

```
function commerce() {
Raphael("commercebounce", function () {
            var r = this;   
            function pathfade() {
            var pa = .1,
                pb = .4, 
                pc = [0, 2], 
                pd = [50, 300], 
                pe = [150, 800], 
                pf = [150, 350], 
                pg = pd[0] + Math.random() * (pd[1] - pd[0]), 
                ph = pe[0] + Math.random() * (pe[1] - pe[0]), 
                pi = pf[0] + Math.random() * (pf[1] - pf[0]),
                bd = .1,
                be = .9,
                pathspot = bd + Math.random() * (be - bd),
                colours = ["215,10,45", "115,115,115"],
                stroke = ["", "- "];
                opacity = pa + Math.random() * (pb - pa), colour = "rgb(" + colours[Math.round(Math.random())] + ")", strokeW = pc[Math.round(Math.random())];
                pj = r.path("M 0 " + pg + " C 0 " + pg + " " + (ph - 100) + " " + pg + " " + ph + " 400 M " + ph + " 400 C " + ph + " 400 " + (ph + 100) + " " + pg + " 960 " + pi).attr({stroke: colour,"stroke-dasharray": stroke[Math.round(Math.random())],"opacity": 0});
                bh = r.circle(0, 0, 7, 7).attr({"stroke-width": this.strokeW,stroke: colour,"stroke-opacity": this.opacity,fill: "none","fill-opacity": 0}).onAnimation(function() {
                var t = this.attr("transform")})
                leng = pj.getTotalLength();
                r.customAttributes.along1 = function (v) {
                    var point = pj.getPointAtLength(v * leng);
                    return {
                        transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
                       }
                };
                return bh.attr({along1:0}), bh.animate({along1:pathspot},300), pj.animate({opacity:opacity},300), pj, bh
             }
pathfade();//how do i repeat this function n times?               
    }); 
}
commerce();
```

Comment: You need to make the "path" you're talking about an parameter for the function pathFade. Then all you do is loop through the amount of times your want calling pathFade with different paths. I'm not sure what the value of path is but it might be the pc, pd, pe, pf variables.

Comment: Also, you need to break pathFade into multiple functions. You have too much crammed into one function which is making it hard to debug.

Comment: do you think you can help me? I have been racking my brain for hours over this problem, and it still isnt settling in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the pathfade() function into multiple simple functions that do only a few task.

There are two main problems.
First, you're placing a semi-colon where there should be a comma during your variable declarations. Look at the stroke variable.
Second, pathfade is returning multiple values when javascript only supports one. Remember that once you return from a function the rest of the statements don't get executed.

And lastly, use a for, do-while, or while loop to repeat your function calls.

Here's the fix. Sorry I didn't have time to refactor.

```
function commerce() {
    Raphael("commercebounce", function () {
        var r = this;
        function pathfade() {
            var pa = 0.5,
            pb = 0.9,
            pc = [0, 2],
            pd = [50, 300],
            pe = [150, 800],
            pf = [150, 350],
            pg = pd[0] + Math.random() * (pd[1] - pd[0]),
            ph = pe[0] + Math.random() * (pe[1] - pe[0]),
            pi = pf[0] + Math.random() * (pf[1] - pf[0]),
            bd = 0.1,
            be = 0.9,
            pathspot = bd + Math.random() * (be - bd),
            colours = ["215,10,45", "115,115,115"],
            stroke = ["", "- "],
            opacity = pa + Math.random() * (pb - pa),
            colour = "rgb(" + colours[Math.round(Math.random())] + ")",
            strokeW = pc[Math.round(Math.random())],
            pj = r.path("M 0 " + pg + " C 0 " + pg + " " + (ph - 100) + " " + pg + " " + ph + " 400 M " + ph + " 400 C " + ph + " 400 " + (ph + 100) + " " + pg + " 960 " + pi).attr({
                    stroke : colour,
                    "stroke-dasharray" : stroke[Math.round(Math.random())],
                    "opacity" : 0
                }),
            bh = r.circle(0, 0, 7, 7).attr({
                    "stroke-width" : this.strokeW,
                    stroke : colour,
                    "stroke-opacity" : this.opacity,
                    fill : "none",
                    "fill-opacity" : 0
                }).onAnimation(function () {
                    var t = this.attr("transform")
                }),
                leng = pj.getTotalLength();
            r.customAttributes.along1 = function (v) {
                var point = pj.getPointAtLength(v * leng);
                return {
                    transform : "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
                }
            };
            bh.attr({
                along1 : 0
            });
            bh.animate({
                along1 : pathspot
            }, 300);
            pj.animate({
                opacity : opacity
            }, 300);
        }
        var i = 10;
        while( i-- ){
            pathfade();
        }
    });
}
commerce();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VEdwG/6/

Your should read "The Elements of C# Style".

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Elements-Style-Kenneth-Baldwin/dp/0521671590/ref=cm_cr-mr-title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521671590)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see a simple loop should be fine. If you're interested this is the fastest way to loop in JavaScript:

```
var i = 10; while (i--) {
//Your code..
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but again, I get the same problem, where all the circles are being animated along the same path, as opposed to each individual path.

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 5; //or however much you want
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    pathfade();
}
```

The `for` loop method is the simplest option here.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when i use that, the circles animate on the SAME path, as opposed to being animated on each path drawn. See here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/VEdwG/5/